Trying to Synchronize and Run 2 Primesense Depth Cameras at the Same Time
I am trying to run 2 Primesense Depth Cameras simultaneously. I was recommended that ROS is able to run the code on this thread: https://answers.ros.org/question/106241/using-multiple-primesenes. I have run into some issues when trying to install ROS for Windows, particularly when I try to input this into the terminal: choco upgrade ros-noetic-desktop_full -y --execution-timeout=0. I receive the following error message, any advice would be greatly appreciated as this is not my area of expertise: C:\Windows\System32>choco upgrade ros-noetic-desktop_full -y --execution-timeout=0
Chocolatey v2.3.0
Upgrading the following packages:
ros-noetic-desktop_full
By upgrading, you accept licenses for the packages.
ros-noetic-desktop_full is not installed. Installing...
ros-noetic-desktop_full not installed. The package was not found with the source(s) listed.
Source(s): 'https://community.chocolatey.org/api/v2/'
NOTE: When you specify explicit sources, it overrides default sources.
If the package version is a prerelease and you didn't specify --pre,
the package may not be found.
Please see https://docs.chocolatey.org/en-us/troubleshooting for more
assistance.
Chocolatey upgraded 0/1 packages. 1 packages failed.
See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).
Failures

ros-noetic-desktop_full - ros-noetic-desktop_full not installed. The package was not found with the source(s) listed.
Source(s): 'https://community.chocolatey.org/api/v2/'
NOTE: When you specify explicit sources, it overrides default sources.
If the package version is a prerelease and you didn't specify --pre,
the package may not be found.
Please see https://docs.chocolatey.org/en-us/troubleshooting for more
assistance.

